# Call to a member function LoggedIn() on null

Tags: php

I'm sure everything is correct. Been breaking my neck over this.

Here is the index.php. I just included the files and calling the functions
from functions.php

I have no idea what's going on at all.
It's a properlly written

```
<?php

    if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == basename(__FILE__)) die("Access denied");
    ob_start();

    require_once 'includes/app/config.php';
    require_once 'includes/app/init.php';

    if (!(empty($maintaince))) {
        header('Location: maintenance.php');
        exit;
    }





  if (!($user -> LoggedIn()) || !($user -> notBanned($odb))){
            header('location: relogin.php');
            die();
        }

    ?>
```

Here is the functions.php

```
<?php

class user {

  function realIP(){
    switch(true){
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      default : return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
  }



  //Kijkt of de gebruiker zijn account geblockeerd is
  function isBanned($odb){
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
    $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($status == 0){

      return true;

  } else {
      //Blockeert de gebruiker, En logt hem uit
      session_destroy();

      return false;

  }

}

  //Kijkt of de gebruiker admin is
  function isadmin(){

    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` =  ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
    $rank = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($rank == 0){

      return true;

  } else {

      return false;

  }
}





//de login functie (bewaart cookies en http header data door middel van @session_start(); )
function LoggedIN(){


  @session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['ID'])){

    return true;

} else {

    return false;

  }

 }
}
?>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? That's not clear.

Comment: *"I'm sure everything is correct."* ... I'm pretty sure it isn't if your `$user` object is `null`

Comment: Where are you defining the `$user` variable?

Comment: Also, the LoggedIN() function is not part of the class, unless you mismatched your braces when entering the code here.

Comment: None of the methods are part of the class looking at it...

Answer (score 0):

You must put your method LoggedIN() in the user class.

As i see you put your method outside, so it can be call outside the class like a classic function.

Comment: I changed the code, But the problem still persists.

Comment: still not in the user class according to your post

Comment: How is it not? I adjusted the braces.

Comment: as much for me. do you have the same error message ? it means user is not defined ? did you do a `new User()` ? what give `var_dump($user);` before the loggedIn() function ? i m sure it is null ;)

Comment: Yes it gives null, I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: where did you do a `$user = new User()` ?

Comment: on the index.php. now i'm getting a plain white screen

Comment: maybe a 500 error, try to check your logs or activate xdebug ;)

Comment: add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top of your file

Comment: Now it works it shows the template again, But it's not redirecting to login.php now.

Comment: and if you dump `$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION['ID']`, do you have values ?

Comment: Getting null too. It's odd. The first method works fine on my other projects.

Comment: Any suggestions?